# Error calling Stored Procedures from EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, stored-procedures

I am trying to access a Store Procedure from EntityFramework.

I have followed these steps:

First of all I have created the Stored Procedure in the Azure Database:

[image]

Then, I have updated the .edmx model from database, selecting only the StoredProcedure I want.

[image]

Once done, in the Function Import I see the StoredProcedure added, but not in the section of StoredProcedures.
What can I do so that it appears here?

[image]

In the Function Import section, all the parameters are set as Input, whereas "MaxReference" should be marked as Output.
How can I change it?

[image]

Although these two issues I have executed the code:

[image]

and I got the following exception:

```
EntityCommandCompilationException
An error occurred while preparing command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

and the InnerException:

```
The function import 'DataModelEntities.AssignMaxSalesRef' cannot be executed because it is not assigned to a storage function.
```

[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may want to refer to this blog post: [FunctionImport is not mapped to a store function Error](http://scottsdalewebstudio.com/blog/functionimport-is-not-mapped-to-a-store-function-error/), that discusses a similar problem. The cause apparently being:

> I had to make changes to a stored procedure and it got deleted from the Entity Data Model Xml file (*.edmx)

With the following step-by-step solution:

> There is an easy solution to fix that error. First open your edmx file and right click on the model that owns the stored procedure. Click Add then  select “Add Function Import”.
>
> Add the same Function Import name that is used in your Context file (if like me, the method was already created but messed up, otherwise is all new and it will be recreared anyways). Select the Stored Procedure Name that you are trying to fix. Choose the Entities and click OK. A new window might pop up “Verify that the FunctionImport name is unique”.
>
> If that is the case, and you get the “Verify that the FunctionImport name is unique” window popup, do the following: Open your *.edmx file and right click over the model you want to update. Select “Show in Model Browser”. Now the Model Browser window opens up. Go to: {myProject}.DataModel > EntityContainer: {somethingEntities} > Function Imports. The function import causing the problem should be there, just delete it and save the *.edmx file.
>
> Try to add the Function Import again. Voila! no issues this time. Save the *.edmx file and recreate the context file (by making a simple non-invasive change like adding a space to the {myProject}.Context.tt file). make sure the new method:
>
> `public virtual ObjectResult<MyEntity> <MyEntity>_NameoftheSP(parametets)` is present in your Context file.

Another troubleshooting resource with similar step-by-step instructions (and images!) on updating the edmx file: [The function import cannot be executed because it is not mapped to a store function](http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.nl/2013/07/the-function-import-cannot-be-executed.html).

Comment: My problem is that when selecting "Add function import" i have no options on the Stored Procedure / Function Name.

Comment: @Ingrid - I have the same issue. Trying to remove the existing SP and resultset and re-add it by using "Update Model from Database" (right-click in EDMX designer) - then select the SP in the dialog (Add).

Answer (score 28):

This post should be a comment but I don't have enough rep to comment.

I was having a similar issue.  My stored procedures were visible and yet I was still getting the error.  This question and answer from Alex led me to look under Function Imports in the Model Browser and I saw that I had multiple entries for each of the stored procedures.  They had sequence numbers to prevent them from being true duplicates.  I removed everything under Function Imports and everything under Stored Procedures / Functions and then re-added them by updating the model from the database.  My issue is now resolved.

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to remove the  p_procname_Result object under Complex Types folder in the model browser.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error:

```
The function import *XXX* cannot be executed because it is not mapped to a store function.
```

when I check, my stored procedure was deleted from database. I created it again, and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the edmx explorer (Diagram Mode), you will see the model explorer window on the side of you diagram.

On the Function Import Section try to find your stored function. Right click on it, then you can modify it.

A Window will be opened, then choose your stored function. a function will mapped after That

Voila, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Working with oracle db on devArt, EF 5.0. What solved it for me is to remove said stored procedure from the model, and then re-add it. Make sure that the stored procedure compiles correctly in the DB, or you wouldn't have the option to add it to the model.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who tried the solution, but still does not work, make sure your proc don't have any issues with invalid columns names, or any other related issues. I got the same error message, but in my case it was an invalid column name reference in the proc.

Answer (score 1):

Following Steps Resolved it for me :
In Visual Studio Open the .edmx file designer .
In the designer right click and select model browser.
On the model browser double click the entity ,Edit Function Import wizard  opens .
In this wizard make sure that the drop-down corresponding to stored-procedure is correctly populated .
Rebuild

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still faces the same issue, perform the following two steps in the Model Browser

1. Delete function from Function Imports in Models tab
2. Delete procedure from store

Then add it again as we do initially [image]

Answer (score 0):

What i usualy do in such cases:
Open up the .edmx file in notepad++
Remove any reference to a stored procedure/view/table that cause problems.
Open up the edmx in visual studio (the designer), and update the model again.
For a stored procedure, make to remove any reference in notepad, then, in visual studio in the update model window, the SP will show up in that tree, and you can select it. By doing this, the code will be regenerated again for that SP.

Answer (score -1):

Simply delete stored procedure that is causing problem save edmx and remove similar name stored procedure like _1 as postfix. remove all such occurrence and then import your updated stored procedure.

Comment: "delete stored procedure", "remove similar name stored procedure", "remove all such occurrence". It's very unclear where all these removals are to take place. To me this seems a repetition of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66981828/861716).