# MVC form to DB via stored procedure issue: stored procedure cannot be executed because it is not mapped to a stored function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to pass form values to a stored procedure that will insert the values into a SQL Server table. However I'm getting an error:

> function import 'appEntities.CreateUser' cannot be executed because its not mapped to a stored function.

Upon googling it, I got this SO post [Error calling Stored Procedures from EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216830/error-calling-stored-procedures-from-entityframework) and I've tried utilizing it. However, I'm not finding a entity model for my stored procedure in my `.edmx` file as the above referenced SO solution suggests. My stored procedure is in my context class as follows:

```
public virtual int CreateUser(string userLanID, string email)
{
        var userLanIDParameter = userLanID != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("UserLanID", userLanID) :
            new ObjectParameter("UserLanID", typeof(string));

        var emailParameter = email != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Email", email) :
            new ObjectParameter("Email", typeof(string));
 return((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("CreateUser", userLanIDParameter, emailParameter)
    }
```

Any assistance with getting this successfully tied in to my stored procedure would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Update**

I've tried this as a solution: http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.nl/2013/07/the-function-import-cannot-be-executed.html but this isn't working.

I deleted the function reimported it as seen below:

[image: There is a function and stored procedure populated.]

However when I do this, I get this error. Fixed it though by running. **Generate Database from Model**

[image]

However after fixing the mappings by running the Generate Database from Models, I lose the stored procure reference as seen below:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this http://scottsdalewebstudio.com/blog/functionimport-is-not-mapped-to-a-store-function-error

Also see this [Error calling Stored Procedures from EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216830/error-calling-stored-procedures-from-entityframework/30217398)

This should help!

Comment: I've tried that, but its not working in this situation